# Streaming WAV files from SQL Server into a Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, stream, wav

There are storing the WAV file in database table as VARBINARY(MAX). 
I used  .ashx handler page to return URL as

```
        Guid id =  Guid.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["RowID"]);
        byte[] bytes;

        string name;
        DAL2.GetImage obj = new DAL2.GetImage();
        obj.ReturnImage(id);
        foreach (var item in obj.ReturnImage(id))
        {
            name = item.ImageFileName;
            bytes = item.Image;

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            context.Response.End();

        }
```

It works on aspx page with  plugin application/x-oleobject, where I used

```
<param name="filename" value="FileCS.ashx?RowID=<%# Eval("RowID") %>">
```

But now we need used it cross-browser (not only IE). So which kind of player should use? I tried flash and silverlight, but it not works with wav. Have you ane idea? Thanks.